got “W18: Invalid character in group name” after applying theme in nvim
I tried to apply theme in nvim 0.7.2 with packer,and after that I got the error
error detected while processing.
/home/alephia/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/tokyonight.nvim/colors/tokyonight.lua:
W18: Invalid character in group name

the content in the file mentioned above is:
require("tokyonight").load({                                                                                                                                                                           
  2   style = vim.o.background == "light" and "day" or nil,
  3 })

I do not know where is the bug.
